# randomly trying to call will not ring once, beep and hang up

Tags: calls, stock-android

I've been experiencing this problem quite randomly.  I've asked some friends around who have Android phones as well and this happens to them as well, so my first thought was that this is an issue with Android.

I try to call a number, and without ever hearing it 'ring' anytime, I get a `Conditional Call Forwarding Active` message and a small beep, and it hangs up.  I then re-try, and sometimes the call goes through, sometimes I get the same message.  Sometimes, on occasions I have to try 4 - 6 times to be able to make the call. On very rare occasions, everytime I try I keep getting the message, beep, and hangs up.  This is extremely frustrating.  Any idea how I can look into this?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 2, stock Android (4.3 as per latest update).

---

**Update 1**

This has nothing to do with Call Forwarding apparently.  I've disabled it from the Call Settings, and now it still happens, without showing the `Call Forwarding activated` message.

Comment: Are you using LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it may be, I did find a solution to this problem.  I noticed that if I switch data / 3G, the call would immediately go through.  I've tried this a lot of times where I couldn't call, switch off 3G and it immediately works.

Also, I've recently switched to CyanogenMod from the native Samsung Android installation, and I don't recall this happening again.  Not sure if it is some kind of bug in Samsung's version of Android.  I'm also using a more recent version of Android, so that could also be the reason.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, except in my case it was 4G.  Answer is still relevant six years later! On my phone, it was under Settings -> "More" -> Cellular Networks -> "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode".

Answer (score 0):

If you go to: `settings-call-call settings-call forwarding-voice call forwarding` -- You will most likely see that for unanswered or unreachable calls it's not disabled because it forwards it to your voicemail, that's why it says conditional call forwarding is active. If you disable all options you won't get the message but then unanswered calls won't go to voicemail

Comment: Yes, it was switched on. I've disabled it and will see if it does it again.  However, ideally I would still have that option because currently using that, my operator can send me a message when I am not in range, that somebody called me.  If it solves the problem, does this mean it's an issue of the operator?

Comment: the problem wasn't solved.  Now it's happening the same, but without the Conditional Call Forwarding active.  That message has got nothing to do with the problem apparently, and it is shown everytime a call is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to my Note 4, I had to reboot, which fixed the problem instantly.

Comment: In my case reboot never fixed it.  For me, I had to switch off 3G strangely enough and calls went through.  Check post marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my call log, and all my text message conversations, cleared my cache, restarted my phone and now it all seems to work.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I tried calling on my Galaxy Note 5 and had same problem with all numbers. I rebooted phone and it started back working.